# Moving point A to point B with attributes using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, point, move

I have an A layer containing points with a XX attribute.
I would like to move (on points A) the points of a layer B with the same XX attribute as A. There is no notion of distances (from a few cm to several kilometers) and I can't find the right solution with QGIS.

[image: move A to B]

Comment: Why move the points, why not simply `select by attribute` from A, then save the selection as the "new B"?

Comment: Because it's for to differents"user" who want sames coordinates. The first from a «classic» bdd, the second from GIS. I known it's not the simply way but I must move the point B.

Comment: I forget, I have 93400 points with 93400 differents attributes (ID from A)

Comment: Sorry, I don't get why B has to be moved, if attributes are similar and A has the correct geolocation.

Comment: For a security problem, points B must have same coordinates than A, but I can't make join. The B point must be move and extract the coordinates to populate database that use for SMS alert. I have no choice. I must move B to A and the only common point is a attribute ID. It is precisely because it is a special case that I ask this question ;-)

Comment: Your special case is... interesting =P There is a tool which allows you to move/shift points by X and Y values. You could define these dynamically (most likely based on the `aggregate`-function) for each matching ID. This is advanced field calculator stuff, but theoretically it should work. Can test though, have to go, sorry.

Comment: Are you still interested in this? A script could do the trick and it shouldn't be too difficult to write.

Answer (score 1):

Create a copy of A as C.

Use refator fields on C to delete all columns except the ID. Perform a join by attribute with C and B and bring all the information.

The new layer C will have the geometries of A and the information of B.

Comment: I'm annoying but I lose points (in B layer) without attributes.

Comment: @pasqal You can select the points of B that are disjointed from C (through the ID column). Copy and paste them in C. Thus C will have all points of A with the information of B and also all points of B that were not linked with A.